# Laravel - get all items in a parent-category

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following table, called `recipe_subcategories`:

[image]

each recipe can be assigned to one parent category and multiple subcategories.

Currently, I have the following code to get the all recipes within a parent category:

```
public function recipes(Request $request) {
        $id = explode('-', $request->idName)[0];
        return Category::where('id',$id)->first()->recipes;
    }
```

The issue is, that if the same recipe belongs to different sub categories in the same parent category, it will return it multiple times.

What's the ideal solution for this issue? The goal is to return all recipes within one parent category (category_id) without duplicates.

Comment: you could replace `Category::where('id',$id)->first()->recipes;` with `Category::find($id)->recipes;`
not helping with the problem but looks slicker, does the same

Comment: Looks like you want to ->groupBy('category_id') ? isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could start on the pivot table, like so:

```php
public function recipes(Request $request)
{
    $categoryId = explode('-', $request->idName)[0];

    $recipeIds = DB::table('recipe_subcategories')
        ->where('category_id', $categoryId)
        ->groupBy('recipe_id')
        ->pluck('recipe_id');

    return Recipe::whereIn('id', $recipeIds)
        ->get();
}
```

I'm not sure how to join these as one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$category = Category::find('id', $categoryId);

$recipes = $category->recipes->unique('category_id');
```

Note : This will get all recipes and then filter then on collection level, not on DB query level.

Comment: Doesn't work - the API retruns only one recipe in this case (the category_id is in pivot table, not in the recipes table)